# How to emit entered value after user finished input using RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

In my Android application I have to process user input by running very complex calculation. So I would like to run it when user is iddle for some period of time. E.g. user entered number 123 and then stopped entering. I want to run calculation when 3 is entered and do not after 1 or 2.
How can I do this using RxJava2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

there is 2 solutions

**1.**

- Listen for events at the application level
- Track the time interval between these events
- Do your calculation if lastInputTime = idleTime

**2.**

- use `TextWatcher` with `afterTextChanged`
- use `postDelayed` handler
- Do your calculation